# Analog stereo out on speakers and headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

this sounds like a pretty dumb question but how can I get audio output on headphones and speakers?  My motherboard is GA-G41M-Combo and doesn't seem to have any digital audio out, but 3 miniplugs coloured blue, green, and red.  I don't want surround, I just want headphones and speakers working at the same time without needing to switch a cable (my headphones have a power on/off toggle).  The motherboard looks like this:

[image]

I currently have speakers plugged into green (working) and headphones plugged into blue (no sound), and can't seem to get output on the headphones after fiddling with the sound settings in Ubuntu 12.04.  Do I really have to buy a splitter?!  The motherboard didn't come with any front panel adapters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a system which I can test this out on, but I believe this section from the Arch Linux PulseAudio website should help you:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Splitting_front.2Frear

To sum up what you should do:

1. Open a terminal and make a back up of `/etc/pulse/default.pa` like this: `cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/default.pa.bak`
2. Open the sound settings menu and change "analog output"'s mode to "Analog Surround 4.0 Output"
3. In the terminal run `pacmd list-sinks` and copy the outputted sink's name. Mine looks like "name: ", and we're interested in the bit in <>, yours should now end in "analog-surround-40".
4. Open default.pa as administrator using `sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa` and add the lines:

> load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=speakers remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-surround-40 channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-left,front-right
>
> load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=headphones remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-surround-40 channels=2 master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right   channel_map=front-left,front-right
>   
>   Replace "master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-surround-40" with the device name you found in step 3.

Now you should be able to select from "Headphones" and "Speakers" in the Sound Settings menu when you want to switch between headphones and speakers.

Comment: thanks .. it looked promising, and i get two new devices appearing called "Remapped Built-in Audio Analogue Surround 4.0", but there is no place on any device to select between headphones and speakers.  in fact, when i select the remapped device the `connector:` combo box disappears completely (?!)

Comment: [Is not recommended](https://askubuntu.com/a/1017537/349837) to edit the system-wide setup. You should work and the user-specific one, on `.config/pulse/`