# PulseAudio & ALSA - Set ports as separate output devices

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I'm trying to separate "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" into two separate devices (front panel audio and back panel audio, they are currently combined).
Using a Realtek ALC887 on Kubuntu 14.04. I've used the front and back panel separately in Windows before just fine, so I know the sound card is capable of doing so.

I followed [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169220/analog-stereo-out-on-speakers-and-headphones) and added the following lines to the bottom of my /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=speakers remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-left,front-right
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=headphones remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo channels=2 master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right channel_map=rear-left,rear-right
```

*I also tried having both with "channel_map=front-left,front-right," as shown in the link*

**Which got me half way there, it gave me two "Remapped Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" devices under my Playback Devices, but the first one is still just combining my speakers (rear panel) and my headphones (front panel), while the second one has no effect.**

Before that, I was only getting audio through the headset, but once I used hdajackretask and set my ports up I managed to get the audio to go through both of them.

"pacmd list-sinks" output (excluding my HDMI audio and keyboard's audio jacks):

The last two are obviously the result of adding the two above lines

```
  * index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9959
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 16.70 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 3
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 2
    linked by: 5
    configured latency: 20.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 7
    properties:
            alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
            device.api = "alsa"
            device.class = "sound"
            alsa.class = "generic"
            alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
            alsa.name = "ALC887-VD Analog"
            alsa.id = "ALC887-VD Analog"
            alsa.subdevice = "0"
            alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
            alsa.device = "0"
            alsa.card = "0"
            alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI SB"
            alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI SB at 0xfe300000 irq 16"
            alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
            device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
            sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
            device.bus = "pci"
            device.vendor.id = "1002"
            device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
            device.product.id = "4383"
            device.product.name = "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
            device.form_factor = "internal"
            device.string = "front:0"
            device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
            device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
            device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
            device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
            device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
            device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
            alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC887-VD"
            alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0887,10438444,00100302"
            module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
            device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
            analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                    properties:

            analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-headphones>
index: 3
    name: <speakers>
    driver: <module-remap-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1000
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 16.55 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 5
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 20.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    module: 21
    properties:
            device.master_device = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo"
            device.class = "filter"
            device.description = "Remapped Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
            device.icon_name = "audio-card"
index: 4
    name: <headphones>
    driver: <module-remap-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1000
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 16.44 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 6
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 20.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    module: 22
    properties:
            device.master_device = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo"
            device.class = "filter"
            device.description = "Remapped Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
            device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

As you can see, "analog-output" and "analog-output-headphones" are both listed under the same sink, "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo"

Is there a way I can fix the problem I'm having (the bolded part above), and/or is there a different route I can take to achieve my goal?

Sorry if I've worded this in a confusing way, this is a totally new area to me. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got a different setup working. Hope this helps you

First of all, my stereo is plugged to the green and the headphone to the black port on the motherboard (+red for the microphone)

In pavucontrol Configuration menu, I set  **Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input** for the profile of my Built-in Audio

Got the name from `pacmd list-sinks`: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-51

/etc/pulse/default.pa:

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=speakers remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-51 channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-left,front-right

load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=headphones remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-51 channels=2 master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right channel_map=front-left,front-right
```

Restart pulseaudio:
`pulseaudio --kill`
`pulseaudio --start`

Now from pavucontrol I can set either of the **Remapped Built-in Audio Analog Surround 5.1** (the names don't show unfortunately..) for each app, which toggles between headphone and stereo

EDIT: When I first tried to achieve this effect on the front panel like you, I noticed that the profile in pavucontrol changed when I plugged the headphone jack in and out. It might help if you set the same profile for both ports before attempting these remaps.

Answer (score 1):

You used `master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right channel_map=rear-left,rear-right` on the second one, when it should have been `master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right channel_map=front-left,front-right`.