# /etc/pulse/default.pa: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, pulseaudio

I've tried to edit this file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. But it gives me this result:

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa: Permission denied
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way to create a user-specific `default.pa` file is working on a copy in the user's HOME. This copy should be stored in `˜/.pulse` or `˜/.config/pulse` whichever directory already exists.

When running pulseaudio in userspace (this is the default) settings we had made in this file will override the system-wide  `/etc/pulse/default.pa` on the next restart of the pulseaudio sound server (e.g. with `pulseaudio -k`).

Only if system-wide settings need to be made for all users we may edit  `/etc/pulse/default.pa` with root privileges. Then we should take care to make a backup copy of that file to be able to revert to the default settings in case something went wrong.