# pulseaudio won't start after changing settings

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio

I've had pulseaudio on my device for a little while. I think the problem started to happen after I played with some 'sessions and startup' settings. I tried to change everything back but it didn't work sadly.

This is the usual pulseaudio failed error that I'm getting:

[image: screenshot of Volume Control]

> Connection to PulseAudio failed. Automatic retry in 5s
>
> In this case this is likely because PULSE_SERVER in the Environment/X11 Root Window Properties or default-server in client.conf is misconfigured.
> This situation can also arise when PulseAudio crashed and left stale details in the X11 Root Window. If this is the case, then PulseAudio should autospawn again, or if this is not configured you should run start-pulseaudio-x11 manually.

Some commands outputs I've seen people post in other posts I've tried that didn't quite work for me

`pulseaudio -k`:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
```

`pulseaudio --start`

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

`pulseaudio -vvv`

https://pastebin.pl/view/b5c54ddf

the red error lines from the above output

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-echo-cancel.c: Can't cancel echo between a sink and its monitor
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-echo-cancel" (argument: "source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

Comment: Did you try to delete all custom user settings? This can e.g. be done by renaming `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.old`. Then restart pulseaudio, or log out and back in.

Comment: @Takkat I tried now and it didn't work :(

Comment: Check in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` if there is a line containing `module-echo-cancel` if yes comment it out (by adding `#` at the beginning of the line) and restart pulseaudio.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz i couldn't edit `default.pa` in the `/etc/pulse/` folder so i copied it to `/.config/pulse/` as i've seen on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017529/etc-pulse-default-pa-permission-denied) and i've commented this line out `load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink` i got no error killing pulse audio but when i tried to start it, it didn't work. it didn't work but it just does nothing however long i wait and the sound icon disappeared from panel.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz i had tried logging out and logging back in but now i tried restarting and it worked!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Edit this file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out a line containing `module-echo-cancel` by adding `#` (hash) at the beginning of the line then restart `pulseaudio`.